# Dynamic filters based on another filter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am looking to create something similar to this http://www.smartoplug.com/partsearch I need my view to sort based off of multiple parameters. So if you select ford in the make, the models dynamically change to only show models that are referenced in ford i.e. F150, F250 etc.

I've looked into hierarchical select, and simple hierarchical select, but it doesn't look like what i am wanting to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

#### [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters)

> Allows the presence of exposed filters on a view to be controlled by
> values in another exposed filter. Dependent filters are hidden when
> not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed
> form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you, but I do question this part tho. "Dependent filters are hidden when not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed form is submitted."

It sounds to me that it's more of a condition then an actual filter. You select a value in filter A and it either shows Filter B or C, but what i need it to do is if you select a value in A it changes the values inside of B